# Create a new row when encountering a special character (eg "/") in a field

Tags: sql, sqlite, mariadb

I'm trying to replicate a record whenever I come across a slash in a specific field.

Background of the problem: I'm trying to compare two lists of data containing item number, item description, and item serial number. One list has item quantity and status information, the other list has item location information, so I'm trying to match up the location list onto the main list. The problem is that both lists were created independently of each other so they both have errors and I've only been able to inner join in SQL about 20%. The rest don't match up because the item number is wrong in one list or the other, the serial number might be missing a digit in one list, and I can't compare the nomenclatures very well either because one might say "Hand Wrench" and the other might say "Wrench, 5mm, socket".

Additionally, one list of data has multiple items, that related to some main item, saved in each record. They did this by storing the multiple serial numbers separated by slashes in the serial number field.

Tried using Levenshtein difference (fuzzy match) in Alteryx for serial number / item number matching. This created way too many false positives because serial numbers are sequential, item numbers are frequently incorrect, and item descriptions might look similar to a human but character length can be wildly different (eg. "Truck" in one list might not match well if the other list has something like "Truck, 8 wheel, cargo, flatbed").

I'm currently trying to just match the lists on if the serial number in one list is contained in the other list (with multiple serial numbers in the serial number field).

Example SQLite code I'm currently using

```
select * from [MISSING ITEMS LIST] as a
left join [RFID TAG SCAN] as b on 
b.[SERIAL NUMBER] like '%' || (a.[SERIAL NUMBER] || '%')
where b.[SERIAL NUMBER] <> '' and b.[SERIAL NUMBER] is not null
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

Recopying this part from above:
So table A might have this:

```
Record# Item#   Description   SN 
1,      156928,  Truck,       1234
2,      209344,  Truck Cover, 5588
```

And Table B might have this

```
Record# Item#   Description SN 
1,      156928, Truck,      5588/01234
```

To make the analysis a little easier, I'd like to convert Table B to this:

```
Record# Item#   Description SN 
1,      156928, Truck,      5588
1,      156928, Truck,      01234
```

Comment: Are you using sqlite or mariadb?

Answer (score 0):

If I assume there is at most one slash, then in MariaDB you can do:

```
select Record, Item, Description
       substring_index(SN, '/', 1) as SN
from t
union all
select Record, Item, Description
       substring_index(SN, '/', -1) as SN
from t
where SN like '%/%';
```

Comment: Ok, awesome. Sometimes there's one slash, sometimes there's 2 or more. So I guess I can iterate this and it'll work out. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @AndrewCarr . . . If there are just a small number, you can add additional similar subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert table B to the format you want use the Text to Columns tool

[image]

In the Configuration, set the Delimiter to "/" and select "Split to Rows"

[image]